# Terminology for cloud service

Tags: terminology, interface

I have a quick question regarding the most frequently used / understandable term:

My company has an online, cloud based business that allows fitness companies such as gyms to manage their whole business (and a smartphone app) from an administration panel (also online).

A lot of the users have basic computer skills, so I would like to know what the best term for this 'administration panel' is?

We have played with Web Admin, Dashboard, Online Portal... However none seem to stick, and can be confusing.

Any other suggestions would be great.

Comment: The best term is what it is: Administration Panel.

Comment: Our issue with that is we aren't even sure that will be understood correctly.

Comment: Dashboard looks like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users are confused by more technical names, try something more contextual, like "My Business" (or, "My Gym" if it's that specific, and possible).

Also, if it's really an entry point to the rest of the app, then just "home" might work and they'll learn which controls and information are available there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Having talked about it some more, your advice is great. Regardless of what the name is, a certain degree of education will have to be done. It also provides us with an option to brand various features of the system (which can be paid for / added to the package) such as 'Brand Home', 'Brand Payments', 'Brand Workouts'.